# Trading in precision for better recall in neural network

Tags: neural-networks, precision-recall, model-evaluation

There's always a tradeoff between precision and recall. I'm dealing with a multi-class problem, where for some classes I have perfect precision but really low recall.

Since for my problem false positives are less of an issue than missing true positives, I want reduce precision in favor of increasing recall for some specific classes, while keeping other things as stable as possible. **What are some ways to trade in precision for better recall?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Weighted loss (ML software like `scikit-learn` or `Keras` let you attach weights to classes, so that you can tell which is more significant)
- Oversampling the low recall classes/undersampling other classes (you should especially check out this method if you have unbalanced classes).

Comment: Could you please provide some example code for weighted loss implementation in Keras or TF?

Comment: @Avis in Keras you can use `loss_weights` argument `model.compile`.